# SwingFXUtils.toFXImage is doesn't working in jar

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX Canvas for drawing a **GameUnit** using the **drawUnit()** method.
When I run an application from IntelliJ using Maven, no errors occur. But when I compile the Jar and run it, the **SwingFXUtils.toFXImage()** method breaks my application. I am 100% sure that the problem is in this method, because I checked it. The **SpriteAnimation.nextSprite()** method returns a **BufferedImage**.

This is main class:

```
public class Game extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("The Game");
        stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(new KeyCharacterCombination(""));
        stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
        stage.setFullScreen(true);

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        GameCanvas canvas = new GameCanvas();
        canvas.widthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        canvas.heightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);

        new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                canvas.clear();
                canvas.drawUnits();
            }
        }.start();

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This is GameCanvas class:

```
public class GameCanvas extends Canvas {
    public void drawUnits(){
        GameData.getAllUnits().forEach(this::drawUnit);
    }

    public void drawUnit(GameUnit unit){
        GraphicsContext context = getGraphicsContext2D();
        SpriteAnimation animation = unit.getAnimation();
        context.drawImage(
                SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(animation.nextSprite(), null),
                unit.getPosition().getX(), unit.getPosition().getY(),
                unit.getWidth(), unit.getHeight()
        );
    }

    public void clear() {
        GraphicsContext context = getGraphicsContext2D();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

This is SpriteAnimation class:

```
public class SpriteAnimation {
    private BufferedImage[] sprites;
    private int counter;
    private int speed;
    private int delay;

    public SpriteAnimation(BufferedImage[] sprites, int speed) {
        this.sprites = sprites;
        this.speed = speed;
        counter = 0;
        delay = 0;
    }

    public BufferedImage nextSprite() {
        if (delay == speed - 1) {
            delay = 0;
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            delay++;
        }
        return sprites[counter % sprites.length];
    }
}
```

This is ImageLoader class:

```
public class ImageLoader implements Loader<BufferedImage> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ImageLoader.class.getName());

    @Override
    public BufferedImage upload(String pathToResource) {
        try (InputStream inputStream = ImageLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pathToResource))
        {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                return ImageIO.read(inputStream);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Can not upload image!");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is example of using ImageLoader class:

```
private static final ImageLoader LOADER = new ImageLoader();


BufferedImage[] unitsImage = {
                LOADER.upload("image/character/TileA1.png"),
                LOADER.upload("image/character/TileA2.png")
        };
```

This is pom-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.some.game</groupId>
    <artifactId>The_Game</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.some.game</groupId>
            <artifactId>GameData</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.some.game</groupId>
            <artifactId>ResourceLoaders</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.some.game.Game</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.some.game.GameLauncher</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is how it must work: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAZ1G.png)

This is how it work: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r8B3.png)

This is result of executing jar-file from command line:

[image]

In this example jar file is working and can be executed by mouse clicking

Reproduced problem in the new project:
POM-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>FXApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>FXAppLauncher</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Main class - FXApp:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class FXApp extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Class-launcher FXAppLauncher:

```
public class FXAppLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FXApp.main(args);
    }
}
```

The project structure: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAsvq.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213241/discussion-on-question-by-anton-sorokin-swingfxutils-tofximage-is-doesnt-workin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your pom file you need to add:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>11</version>
    </dependency>
```

That should include the swing module.

Here is a small class to test, if I do not include the `javafx.swing`module then it shows me an error message.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;


public class BuffToFx extends Application{


@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(5, 5);

        primaryStage.setTitle("BufferImage to Fx");

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(512, 512, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawOval(256, 256, 128, 128);

        try{
            ImageView view = new ImageView( javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(img, null) );
            root.getChildren().add(view);
        } catch(Error e){
            Text error = new Text(e.toString());
            root.getChildren().add(error);
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 790, 675);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I can reproduce my problem in the new project.
Now I’ll lay out a complete example with all the code and the pom file

Comment: @AntonSorokin Great, you definitely should do that. I suspect if you make the suggested change to your pom it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Complete! New Project in the end of the post.

Comment: @AntonSorokin great, and did you try the suggested change?

Comment: YES!!! Thank you so much! Adding new module in pom is solved the problem! :)

Comment: Great! Another thing you might try is to look at where IntelliJ finds your java 11. It would be really helpful in the future to be able to run from the command line because you would see the stacktrace.